# Extract only first match with Regex in Scala

Tags: regex, json, scala

I'm trying to extract a specific string value from a JSON-formatted string in Scala.  However, this is going to be used in a production environment, so I'm concerned about efficiency.  Currently, I'm currently using the bit of code below:

```
val r = """identifier=\{S: ([\w\.]+),""".r
var identifier: String = "";
r.findAllIn(queryResult toString).matchData foreach {
  m => identifier = m.group(1)
}
```

My concern is efficiency.  I don't need to validate the JSON itself (that's being produced by AWS, so I'm assuming it's good, and even if it's not, I can't change it), so there's no good reason to go through all the overhead of parsing it out.

That said, can I do this more efficiently with a regex, or would I have to go down to the level of finding the first occurence of 'identifier={S: ', then the next occurence of ',' after that, and get the substring between the two?  I was trying to do something with `r.findFirstIn` but I can't figure out a way to extract the group I want from that.

Or is there some other super efficient thing I'm not aware of that I could be doing?

Comment: Since it is in production environment, use a JSON parser please.

Comment: Better to use a well-established parser than try parsing it yourself via regex.  Premature optimization < Completeness

Comment: How big is your json string ? Also `identifier=somestring` seem like a string value within json. It would be a lot clearer if you can share a sample json you are dealing with.

Comment: The JSON string is quite large, hence why I didn't want the overhead of parsing the entire thing.  And when I say 'production', I don't mean stuff that goes on to consumers - I mean something we're using to test our server which interacts with a DB.

Comment: @nhahtdh I should also mention that I don't know if a normal JSON parser will parse content from the response to AWS DynamoDB.  The formal JSON specification says a string should be written `"content"` but what I get back is just `S: content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the first match:

```
r.findFirstMatchIn(queryResult.toString).map(_.group(1))
```

(Will be an `Option[String]`.)

That said, I'd use a streaming JSON parser every time over a regex.  Yes, the regex is faster, but unless this is *really* a bottleneck, I would be more worried about accuracy.

Comment: Neater to use `r.unanchored`, `s match { case ru(g) => }`. Click the triangle at: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/2.11.x/api/2.11.x/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex@unanchored:scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex